# Conditionally replace values with NA as they appear in another data frame

Tags: r, na

Sorry I tried posting this but this is my first time posting here. I am relatively new to R and have an issue with 2 data frames which I need to address. They are based on 2 sets of date/time Meteorological data that I need to compare, but first I need to make all values NA where they appear in my first df.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(WSpeed=c(5,3,6,7), WDirection=c(150,160,30,40), 
                  Rain=c(NA,NA,3,10), RH=c(NA,15,90,NA))
DF2 <- data.frame(WSpeed=c(10,5,2,8), WDirection=c(160,150,40,25), 
                   Rain=c(5,10,3,10), RH=c(20,15,90,50))
```

to give me

```
DF1
  WSpeed WDirection Rain RH
1      5        150   NA NA
2      3        160   NA 15
3      6         30    3 90
4      7         40   10 NA

DF2
   WSpeed WDirection Rain RH
1     10        160    5 20
2      5        150   10 15
3      2         40    3 90
4      8         25   10 50
```

I need my DF2 to resemble this:

```
  WSpeed WDirection Rain RH
1     10        160   NA NA
2      5        150   NA 15
3      2         40    3 90
4      8         25   10 NA
```

I also have a date/time column in each row. I have searched and can't find an answer and was hoping if someone could help with a relatively simple answer.

Thanking in advance!

Comment: In your question, what is the condition?  DId you meant `i1 <- is.na(DF1);
 DF1[i1] <- DF2[i1]`

Comment: Hi, Sorry I tried posting this but this is my first time posting here. I am relatively new to R and have an issue with 2 data frames which I need to address. They are based on 2 sets of date/time Meteorological data that I need to compare, but first I need to make all values NA where they appear in my first df. I need my df2 to look like this :

Comment: In that case,, try the code I posted in the comments assuming that the data are ordered (no info about merge or anything in your post)

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have edited my question, perhaps I have asked it better.

Comment: Just do `DF2[is.na(DF1)] <- NA`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that worked!